# Is it possible to make a custom post that adds multiple pages?

Tags: posts, customization

I'm trying to make a custom post for an event that contains multiple pages like [this](https://www.youngstartup.com/newyork2018/index.php) event page. Whenever someone would add an "event" an event homepage, agenda page, venue page, and registration page would be generated. Is this possible and does it make any sense to do it rather than having a separate page template for each one and linking them?

If it is possible, where are some good resources to read up on this. My impression from the WordPress docs is that it is impossible - but I'm not sure.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option would be to set up a MultiSite. That way each "subsite" is for one event, and when the subsite is created you can programmatically create each Page needed. It just depends on your exact needs whether or not this would be overkill.

If you need to have all events linked in some way - such as a central calendar - you probably want to set up a Custom Post Type of "event" and make it hierarchical, so you can have each event as a top-level (parent) post, and set the agenda, registration, and venue pages as children. Really the only benefit to having these as a custom post type rather than a page would be to keep them separate from other content types. If you do anything fancy like adding event schema it's also easier to add this to a CPT than it is to a generic Page.

Comment: Multisite might be a bit of overkill, IMHO. If there are many events, then there are many tables that will be created - about 8-9 tables for each multisite site. That might make the hosting place mad; many don't like databases with a large number of tables, especially at the lower-levels (cheaper) of hosting plans. Using a process to create event-named pages would be better, IMHO.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. Start here https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_insert_post/ . There is sample code on that page.

You can create any post type: page, post, etc. Lots of googles on how to do this.

Comment: Thanks! I'll get started! Just to clarify - I now have it set up that there are custom pages - but you have to make one page for the home page one for the agenda etc. You're not talking about that - right?

Comment: If you want everything on one site (not multisite with each multisite a separate event, which I think would be a bit of overkill, not to mention causing excessive database size; see comment on the other answer), then your process could create the 'main' page for the event, and other pages that are linked to the event. You could even put those links in the content of the main page ('event-12345') - with links having a standard page name pattern like 'event-12345_tickets', 'event-12345_agenda', etc.